# Setting up Git-bash to web developing and terminal using

Tags: git, web, git-bash

I have installed Git-bash but commands like: man, open,... don't work. I can't even create one new tab.

I have linux in dual boot but i want to use win7 because it's more practical. There is a way to set upo Git-bash to be like terminal in linux? with almost all the features?

(It's for web develop)

Comment: Have you tried [cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)?

Comment: You can use [minGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: printenv don't work too :(

Comment: cygwin /minGW insted of git-bash?

Answer (score 0):

- Is `git --version` getting you an answer?
- Are you aware, that you need a bash terminal/emulation ([see here](https://msysgit.github.io/) and commenters above), no unix command is going to work in a dosbox right away?
- That being said, many unix command line tools as plain vanilla exe's (no Cygwin, etc. needed) can be found at [unxutils.sf.net](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) (no updates since 2006, but still handy with all those tail, cat, ls, grep, ...).
- If you talk about practical and you are a Windows user anyway, I strongly recommend giving [smartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) a look, which is free for private use. (saves my back (and brain) on a daily basis).

Comment: git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1